What does お構い申し mean here?
From Kokoro part 1 chapter 29:

二人はまただらだら坂の中途にある家の前へ来た。はいる時には誰もいる気色の見えなかった縁に、お上さんが、十五、六の娘を相手に、糸巻へ糸を巻きつけていた。二人は大きな金魚鉢の横から、「どうもお邪魔をしました」と挨拶した。お上さんは「いいえお構い申しも致しませんで」と礼を返した後、先刻小供にやった白銅の礼を述べた。

I am not familiar with お構い申し. It seems to be a combination of お構い, which means もてなし, and 申し, which probably means 挨拶? Then いいえお構い申しも致しませんで literally means, "nah, I didn't greet you or provide you any hospitality, so." Is that right?

申し is a [謙譲語]{けんじょうご} suffix (which accords with the choice of 致す for the main verb). It's the same root word as in the self-introduction form 〇〇と申します and the apology form 申し[訳]{わけ}[無]{な}い. There are a few different context-sensitive glosses in E-J dictionaries, but the core meaning as I understand it is something like "have the undeserved honour of ~". (It's also used as the 謙譲語 form of 言う; I don't quite understand that but I'm sure it makes sense with historical context.) When you state your name this way, you humbly suppose that you don't deserve such a title; when you apologize, you indicate that there is no excuse that would entitle your unworthy self to have done whatever it was.
As a suffix to お構い, it doesn't really add meaning, just that strong nuance of humility. The speaker supposedly should have felt honoured to offer hospitality, yet still failed to do so. (The literal meaning of this sort of ritual language often seems over-the-top.)
In context, もてなし seems to me like a reasonable approximation to お構い; but of course you use the latter in 謙譲語, since that implies using [丁寧語]{ていねいご} for the concept you're elevating above yourself.

It turns out that お/ご〜申す is one of the so called kenjougo verb construction like お/ご～する. More information can found in definition 4 in Daijisen entry for 申す.
